# How to highlight current menu item in bootstrap in Laravel?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

working with laravel 5.6 and I have following sidebar.blade.php file sidebar.blade.php

```
<style type="text/css">
.list-group {

     margin:auto;
     float:left;
     padding-top:20px;
    }
    .lead {

     margin:auto;
     left:0;
     right:0;
     padding-top:10%;
    }
</style>

 <div class="list-group">

    <a href="#" class="list-group-item active"><i class="fa fa-key"></i> <span>App Settings</span></a>
    <a href="{{route('vehicles.myads')}}" class="list-group-item" ><i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i> <span>My Ads</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i> <span>Support</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-left"></i> <span>Sandbox Account</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><i class="fa fa-book"></i> <span>QuickStart Overview</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><i class="fa fa-compass"></i> <span>Documentation</span></a>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

$('.list-group-item').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.list-group-item').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
  </script>
```

now I need highlight current menu item in above sidebar.blade.php file how can do it? current jquery codes is working only highlight in same page but when I go using link other page current link it is not highlight (as an example if I go to myads link from home page in myads page myads menu is not highlight)

**Edit**
hope to use this sidemenu blade file as include file with other blade files

Comment: this could save your time https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40587546/how-to-highlight-current-page-with-bootstrap-in-laravel-5-2

Comment: Check this link : https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/best-practice-for-handling-active-menu-item-in-l5

Answer (score 4):

For example, if your URL has sites/*/edit you can check it in this way.

```
<a href="#" class="list-group-item {{ request()->is('sites/*/edit') ? 'active' : '' }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

use My Helper Functions which I have Created for Handling all the situations of the active menu

https://gist.github.com/AManojKiran/56a9fd3332795edec8cc80b4dd4928d3

Comment: Gist returns 404.